# Submit form in parent window from popup?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 HTML files like this.

**parent.html**

```
<form method='get' action=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='something'>
    <input type='button' name='submit' value='Submit' onclick='newwindow=window.open("child.html","popup","height=150,width=200");'>
</form>
```

**child.html**

```
Enter Something Here<br />
<input type='text' name='somethingelse'>
<input type='button' name='submit' value='OK'>
```

When the user clicks on *Submit* button in **parent**, a new popup window will show up and ask him to enter something.

Can anybody please tell me how can I transfer the value of input[somethingelse] from 
**child** to input[something] and submit the form in **parent** after the user has clicked *OK*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get a reference to the form in the parent window via `window.opener.document`, like this:

```
var form = window.opener.document.getElementById("theFormID");
```

(You'd give the form an ID, although there are other ways to do it.)

Then you can access the fields in that form, and of course set their `.value` property, and you can submit the form via its `.submit()` function.

But fair warning: Users don't like pop-ups. If there's any way you can just incorporate the other field into the form, I would recommend that instead.

Here's a full example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/abiviq/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/abiviq/1/edit) | [Source of popup](http://jsbin.com/urawum/1/edit)

The main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="theForm" action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="theField" name="theField">
    <br><input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="window.open('/urawum/1','','height=400,width=400'); return false;">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The popup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Please fill in more information:</p>
  <input type="text" id="thePopupField">
  <br><input type="button" value="Send Form" onclick="doTheSubmit();">
  <script>
    function doTheSubmit() {
      var doc = window.opener.document,
          theForm = doc.getElementById("theForm"),
          theField = doc.getElementById("theField");
      theField.value = document.getElementById("thePopupField").value;
      window.close();
      theForm.submit();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run that, you find that when you click `Send` on the main page, it does the popup. If you fill in a value in the popup and click `Send Form`, the popup disappears and the form is submitted. You can tell the form is submitted with the value because I've used `method="GET"` and so you can see `theField=yourValue` in the query string in the URL of the resulting page. For instance, if you type "my value" into the popup, you'll see the URL `http://jsbin.com/abiviq/1?theField=my+value` in the main page after the form submit. (But your form presumably uses `POST` rather than `GET`, I'm just using `GET` to demonstrate.)

Comment: That's an excellent answer! Thank you very much for your explanation too. I have tried and it work exactly the way I wanted.

Comment: @user433531: Good deal, glad that helped!

Comment: @ Lukasz Koziara: Thanks, but if I'd wanted to indent it that way, I would have. Best,

Answer (score -1):

```
        $('#popupformid').submit(function() {

                var myVar = $('#somethingelseid').val();
                $('input:text.something').val(myVar);
                document.getElementById("formID").submit();
         });
```

Comment: The OP said nothing about jQuery. Please don't post jQuery-only answers to non-jQuery questions.

Comment: T.J. Crowder, I think it's beneficial to also see a JQuery variation even if not requested. Is there a smoother way to go about such?