# How to do a page refresh after submitting and executing an update statement to show the updated values?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, updating, page-refresh

I have to click on the update button and then do an update in database and a refresh to show the updated values on the same page. These values must be updated in the database as well. I have been trying to do the refresh but it does not work. Need some help and guidance. Is there any other alternative besides page refresh? Can it be done without page refresh?

```
      <?php
      //initalizing the query
      $id =  $_GET['id'];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM new_default_reports WHERE id = '$id'";
      $result = $conn->query($query);
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
      ?>

      <input type="button" id="btnShow" style="overflow:hidden;margin- left:1400px;font-weight:bold;background-color:lightgray" value="Edit Default Reports" />
      <div id="dialog" align="center">
      <form action = "" method="post">
      <label> SQL Statement</label>
      <textarea name="sqlst" style="width:100%;height:40%;" class = "form-control"><?php echo $row['sql_statement']?></textarea><br>
      <label> X axis: </label>
      <input type="text" name="x" class = "form-control" value="<?php echo $row['x_axis'] ?>"><br>
      <label> Y axis: </label>
      <input type="text" name="y" class = "form-control"  value="<?php echo $row['y_axis'] ?>"><br>
      <input type="submit" name = "set" value="Update" style="background-color:darkred;width:100px;color:white;font-weight:bold" onclick="window.location.reload();"/>
      </form>
      </div>

      <?php 
      if (isset($_POST['set'])){
      $query = "UPDATE new_default_reports SET sql_statement ='{$_POST['sqlst']}', x_axis ='{$_POST['x']}', y_axis = '{$_POST['y']}' where id = $id";
      $result = $conn->query($query);
      header("Refresh: 0; url=previewgraphs.php?id=".$id);
      }
      ?>
```

UPDATED:

```
  <input type="button" id="btnShow"
   style="overflow:hidden; margin-left:1400px; font-weight:bold; background-color:lightgray" value="Edit Default Reports">
<div id="dialog" align="center">
<form action="previewgraphs.php?id=$id" method="post">
    <label>SQL Statement</label>
    <textarea name="sqlst" style="width:100%; height:40%;" class="form-control">
        <?php echo $row['sql_statement']?>
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <label>X axis: </label>
    <input type="text" name="x" class="form-control"
           value="<?php echo $row['x_axis'] ?>">
    <br>
    <label>Y axis: </label>
    <input type="text" name="y" class="form-control"
           value="<?php echo $row['y_axis'] ?>">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="set" value="Update"
           style="background-color:darkred;width:100px;color:white;font-weight:bold">
    <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit the form">
</form>
 </div>

   <?php 
   if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
  $query = "UPDATE new_default_reports SET sql_statement  ='{$_POST['sqlst']}', x_axis ='{$_POST['x']}', y_axis = '{$_POST['y']}' where id = $id";
  $result = $conn->query($query);

  // make a query to get the updated result and display it on the page
  $select_query = "SELECT sql_statement, x_xis, y_axis FROM new_default_reports WHERE id = $id";
  $select_result = $conn->query($select_query);
  if ($select_result->num_rows == 1) {
      echo "You have successfully updated the database.";
      $row = $select_result->fetch_assoc();
      echo $row['sql_statement'];
      echo $row['x_axis'];
      echo $row['y_axis'];
  }
}
  ?>
```

Comment: How about `header('Location:your_url')` ?

Comment: also dosent work. The updated values not showing on the page. Only database updating

Comment: why not simply update the database, before you fetch the table?

Comment: I'd do it without refreshing, but rather sending the form to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. Put this as a value of the attribute `action`.

Comment: @cezar - How do i go about doing it? Possible to guide a little?

Comment: Before I answer, how is this page launched initially. Do you click on a anchor tag or press a button on another page. In other words how do you set `$ID` the first time the page loads?

Comment: Its a pop up box with all these input boxes on the same page. Once update button is clicked, it goes back to the previewgraphs.php?id=1 and updates the page without clicking refresh

Comment: So what is this script you posted called?

Comment: @DivyaK So If I now understand you, this is a pop up box with the form, that updates the caller page. You had to tell us immediatelly about the pop up box, as it changes the perception. Here is another SO question that has a similiar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300117/submit-form-in-parent-window-from-popup. Is it maybe what are you looking for?

Comment: @cezar: Yes - I have a pop up box with all the form fields to update my database values. And when the popup box closes, it goes back to the page and updates the values. The link u sent is not what im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take updated value from the database after update query.

Please try this code :-

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['set'])){
        $query = "UPDATE new_default_reports SET sql_statement ='{$_POST['sqlst']}', x_axis ='{$_POST['x']}', y_axis = '{$_POST['y']}' where id = $id";
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        $select_query = "SELECT * FROM new_default_reports where id = $id";
        $select_result= $conn->query($select_query );
        $row = $select_result->fetch_assoc();
    }
?>

<input type="button" id="btnShow" style="overflow:hidden;margin- left:1400px;font-weight:bold;background-color:lightgray" value="Edit Default Reports" />
<div id="dialog" align="center">
    <form action = "" method="post">
        <label> SQL Statement</label>
        <textarea name="sqlst" style="width:100%;height:40%;" class = "form-control"><?php echo $row['sql_statement']?></textarea><br>
        <label> X axis: </label>
        <input type="text" name="x" class = "form-control" value="<?php echo $row['x_axis'] ?>"><br>
        <label> Y axis: </label>
        <input type="text" name="y" class = "form-control"  value="<?php echo $row['y_axis'] ?>"><br>
        <input type="submit" name = "set" value="Update" style="background-color:darkred;width:100px;color:white;font-weight:bold" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Answer (score 0):

The `header` function does not work in your case because you have already output before trying to set the header.
The solution is to reverse the php and html code such that the php code is on the very beginning of the document.

Little side note, now you actually do not need the refresh anymore.

**EDIT** included select query.

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['set'])){
        $query = "UPDATE new_default_reports SET sql_statement ='{$_POST['sqlst']}', x_axis ='{$_POST['x']}', y_axis = '{$_POST['y']}' where id = $id";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        //header("Refresh: 0; url=previewgraphs.php?id=".$id);//not needed
        $select_query = "SELECT sql_statement, x_xis, y_axis FROM new_default_reports WHERE id = $id";
        $select_result = $conn->query($select_query);
        if ($select_result->num_rows == 1) {
            $row = $select_result->fetch_assoc();
        }
    }

?>

 <input type="button" id="btnShow" style="overflow:hidden;margin- left:1400px;font-weight:bold;background-color:lightgray" value="Edit Default Reports" />
<div id="dialog" align="center">
    <form action = "" method="post">
        <label> SQL Statement</label>
        <textarea name="sqlst" style="width:100%;height:40%;" class = "form-control"><?php echo $row['sql_statement']?></textarea><br>
        <label> X axis: </label>
        <input type="text" name="x" class = "form-control" value="<?php echo $row['x_axis'] ?>"><br>
        <label> Y axis: </label>
        <input type="text" name="y" class = "form-control"  value="<?php echo $row['y_axis'] ?>"><br>
        <input type="submit" name = "set" value="Update" style="background-color:darkred;width:100px;color:white;font-weight:bold" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And remove `onclick="window.location.reload();"`

Comment: Not working. It is not updating the page based on the updated database values

Comment: Where do you get the result row then? Because that should be below the update query.

Comment: But somewhere you need a mysql select statement, do you already have it somewhere on your page? If yes, provide it. It should be locatef below the update query.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it works for you. One question though, where do you get the value if $id?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
<input type="button" id="btnShow"
       style="overflow:hidden; margin-left:1400px; font-weight:bold; background-color:lightgray" value="Edit Default Reports">
<div id="dialog" align="center">
    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"
          method="post">
        <label>SQL Statement</label>
        <textarea name="sqlst" style="width:100%; height:40%;" class="form-control">
            <?php echo $row['sql_statement']?>
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <label>X axis: </label>
        <input type="text" name="x" class="form-control"
               value="<?php echo $row['x_axis'] ?>">
        <br>
        <label>Y axis: </label>
        <input type="text" name="y" class="form-control"
               value="<?php echo $row['y_axis'] ?>">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="set" value="Update"
               style="background-color:darkred;width:100px;color:white;font-weight:bold"">
        <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit the form">
    </form>
</div>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
      $query = "UPDATE new_default_reports SET sql_statement  ='{$_POST['sqlst']}', x_axis ='{$_POST['x']}', y_axis = '{$_POST['y']}' where id = $id";
      $result = $conn->query($query);

      // make a query to get the updated result and display it on the page
      $select_query = "SELECT sql_statement, x_axis, y_axis FROM new_default_reports WHERE id = $id";
      $select_result = $conn->query($select_query);
      if ($select_result->num_rows == 1) {
          echo "You have successfully updated the database.";
          $row = $select_result->fetch_assoc();
          echo $row['sql_statement'];
          echo $row['x_axis'];
          echo $row['y_axis'];
      }
    }
?>
```

So you wouldn't need to refresh the page, but rather you send the form to itself. It will result in another request. If the form has been sent the php code in the if-clause get executed and the database will be updated. Than you have the task to make a select query to get the updated result and display it on the page.

Should the user open the page with the form per get request, she is not going to see any results from the database.

When writing HTML you should also try to be consistent and keep the code conventions throughout your project. For single tags XML-like style is `<input \>`, HTML-style is `<input>`.

I hope this helps you and also gives you some alternative view how to solve your problem.

EDIT:

I removed the onclick event from your input element and added a submit button. When checking if the form has been sent, look for the submit button in your if-clause. If you like you can use `<button type="submit">Submit the form</button>` instead of `<input type="submit">`

ANOTHER EDIT:

I added simple select query and displayed the updated report on the page.
This is my idea about it:

- user sends GET request - form is displayed
- user sends POST request (submitting the form) - it is sent to itself, the from is displayed and the user gets feedback if update was successful, the udpated values being displayed

When creating something like this I always think on CRUD - create, retrieve, update, display.

The form should update an entry in the database.
For the retrieve part you should better use another view, displaying only the result, but not the form.

You could certainly send the form to the page where the result is displayed*, but I think that would be a bad practice. The user needs some feedback if the update action was successful.

for example something like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo 'previewgraphs?id=$id'; ?>">
```

You shouldn't squeeze to much logic into one part. Rethink your design. I'd also reccomend you to use a framework that implements the MVC pattern. You have a big choice. The framework will take care about many things and provide you also semantic URLs, so you'll have something like:

```
/reports
/reports/1
```

instead of appending all the parameters to the URL.

Comment: Dosent work at all. It brings me back to previewgraphs.php instead of previewgraphs.php?id=1. Also do i have to make a query to get the updated result and display it on the page?

Comment: Brings me back to previewgraphs.php instead of previewgraphs.php?id=1

Comment: That's the point. previewgraphs.php sends the form to itself. I'll extend my answer to explain it better.

Comment: but i have to bring it back to the id page which is previewgraphs.php?id=1

Comment: As @Bas van Stein already mentioned, you have to make your select query after the update query. In my example you could take out the select query out of the if-clause, so the result is always displayed and if you want to display it above the form, then move the whole php-block.

Comment: If you want to bring it back to previewgraphs.php?id=1 then use that in the form action. The answer and comments from Bas van Stein are also very helpful. You don't need refresh. When sending the form a POST request is issued and the user is brought to another page. The updated result will be displayed without the need to refresh anything.

Answer (score -1):

first restructure your code.
The first part of your code must save the values in case changes are being submitted. Then you read from the database again and show results.

However this could be a browser or proxy caching problem. I have a couple of tags that have been very helpful:

```
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

put them in the html < head > section .  Older IEs do weird things with proxys sometimes.

Cheers, Karsten

Comment: How would that make a difference ?

Comment: your browser/proxy thinks nothing has changed and shows you a older copy. These tags make shure the browser never saves it.

Comment: I need to ensure the page is refreshed and the content is updated based on whatever i update in the form.